# как восстановить жесткий диск после форматирования

Tags: hdd, восстановление

в программе AOMEI Partition Assistant попытался изменить тип hdd диска с GPT на MBR, он не смог это сделать и отформотировал весь диск со всеми разделами, возможно ли его восстановить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Первые два шага - это то, как делаю лично я. Это позволяет гарантироать возможность не запороть данные окончательно (если диск физически исправен) и не тратить много времени на повторные попытки:*

1. Снять с диска образ, диск убрать в надежное место, далее работать только с образом.
2. Образ желательно разместить на CoW-файловой системе (CEPH, ZFS) и сразу сделать снапшот
3. Обычно такой казус легко лечится инстурментом [TestDisk](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Comment: в этой же программе есть "мастер восстановления раздела", но там он уже показывает, что диск MBR, мне использовать его или лучше ваш метод?

Comment: Именно для того чтобы не выбирать между программами, я снимаю образ, чтобы иметь возможность гарантированно вернуться к начальному состоянию образа и попробовать все инструменты.

Comment: Как снять образ с абсолютно пустого диска на котором нет разделов ?

Comment: Для того, чтобы снять образ, разделы не нужны. На линуксе, которым я пользуюсь (и на котором я починил не одну поломанную ФС, решая админские задачи), это стандартная задача - берем dd_rescue и вперед.

Comment: Как вы в итоге поступили?

Comment: я воспользовался мастером восстановления раздела